# How to get facebook post(keyword search) using API

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, jsonp

I am trying to get facebook public post through keyword search. 
I tried this 
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET&grant_type=client_credentials 
It shows error
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Missing redirect_uri parameter.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 191
   }
}

Is it possible to get post. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Public Post search is deprecated, there is no way to search for posts (and keywords) anymore: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog